# Utilizing versioning with ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, versioning, arcgis-collector, arcgis-portal

I have done a lot of research on the internet with this and I am unable to find a cut and dry answer. I am utilizing ArcMap 10.3.1. and PostgreSQL 9.3. I have been able to get everything set up between ArcMap and PostgreSQL. I created a enterprise geodatabase, imported some point data, registered the database with the server, and successfully published the data to ArcGIS Portal. Within Portal, I have made a map and developed an appropriate web application. With this I can successfully edit the data in the PostgreSQL database utilizing ArcGIS Collector.

I would like to utilize versioning in order to keep track of the changes that are in being made in the field. I have successfully created a version that is public and protected the DEFAULT version. When i do this, I am unable to sync the edits back to the PostgreSQL database.

Has anyone any insight or had any luck getting versioning to work with ArcGIS Collector?

Comment: After you created the new version, did you re-publish it so that the feature service uses the new version?

Comment: Yes I did republish it. One thought I had is do I need to create a user with the same login information as the login for collector? On the other hand, if it is public it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Before dealing with Collector, I would first confirm that you can edit via the feature service. This can be done by building a web app (with an editor widget) or maybe just by deleting a feature using the HTML page on the REST endpoint.

Comment: To be more specific, did you republish the service so that it is pointing to your new version? You ahould have had to register the data connection. Protecting default may have removed the server user editing access...

Comment: Can you add any errors you see in the debug logs for server when you try to create a replica on the service?

Comment: I realized that I republished the DEFAULT protected version rather than switching versions prior to republishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to publishing the data to portal, I changes the table of contents to list by source. Then right clicked the database and clicked change version. I selected the version that I created for the field work in collector and hit OK. I was then working with the Field version rather than the DEFAULT version.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to get versioned data to work with collector, I have relied on archiving enabled data only.

I believe it is possible and this link outlined steps you may want to try (I haven't yet).

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/offline-maps-and-versioned-data.htm

Implies that you can use versioned data with collector if you

> In Feature Service Advanced Options, the project manager chooses the Create a version for each user option. 
>   With this option, 
>   the first time a field worker downloads a map, a version is created for that worker. This version is then used when the 
>   worker synchronizes edits.

Comment: It's best practice to outline the method in you answer rather than just a link as they can get removed.  Could you expand you answer with what your link outlines.